# How to update .env value of container definitions in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, aws-ecs

[image]

I’m new to AWS ECS deployment. This is my first time.

I have updated the `.env` in my container definition on my AWS account.

But when I run `docker exec e718a29eb0e3 env` in my container I still seeing the latest value updated.

I even tried

`node@db39b382163a:/api$ pm2 restart all`

I still not seeing it updated.

Do I need to restart something else ?

Comment: Is the `.env` a file in the Docker container or are you passing environment variables through the task definition?

Comment: I am trying to pass the .env via task definition ? Should I create a .env ? Which one is the best practice (create .env on docker container or via the task definition )?

Comment: Via the task definition, otherwise you'll have to rebuild your container each time (even if you layer it right, it's still not the way to go). Are you using Cloudformation or the console to update the task? In either case, after updating the container definitions you still need to create a new revision and then run it to have the env vars updated

Answer (score 0):

The native CodePipeline -> ECS integration will only update the container definitions' image attribute so you cannot use it to manage environment variables. you have a couple of other options:

You can use a Lambda function instead to drive your deployment and do something similar to the above to edit both the image and environment attributes.
If you're using CloudFormation to manage your task definition and service, you can use these templates to manage those fields instead of the native integration.